# Render an InputText based on Selected Option

Tags: visualforce, selectlist, selectoption

In my VF page I have an `apex:selectList` with a List of Vendors *(e.g. Alcatel,Cisco ec..)*, the last option is *"Other"*.

When the user select "Other" an `apex:inputText` should be rendered  where he can writes the Vendor. I'm not able to render the *inputText* Field 
 My VF page:

```
<apex:outputPanel id="vendor2">
<p><b> Vendor: </b></p>
<apex:selectList value="{!vendor}" multiselect="False" size="1">
    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!specifyVendor}" rerender="otherPanel"/>
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!vendors}"/>
</apex:selectList><p/>
</apex:outputPanel>
<br/>
<apex:outputPanel id="otherPanel">
    <apex:inputText value="{!otherVendor}" rendered="{!vendor=='Other'}"> Other: </apex:inputText>
</apex:outputPanel>    
<br/><br/>
```

The custom controller:

```
    public with sharing class ExcelPageController {

        public String vendor {get; set;}//Vendor Name
        public String otherVendor {get; set;}//Vendor Name

        public List<SelectOption> getVendors(){
            System.debug('getVendors');    
            List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
            options.add(new SelectOption('Cisco','Cisco'));
            options.add(new SelectOption('Alcatel','Alcatel'));
            options.add(new SelectOption('Tibco','Tibco'));
            options.add(new SelectOption('Other','Other'));
            return options;
        }
    public PageReference specifyVendor(){
        System.debug(vendor);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Place `<apex:inputText>` in separate `outputPanel` and try to rerender that panel on `actionSupport` call.

Also added at `<apex:ouputText>` to confirm the value is correctly be displayed

```
<apex:page controller="ExcelPageController">
<apex:form >
    <apex:outputPanel id="vendor2">
        <p><b>Vendor:</b></p>
        <apex:selectList value="{!vendor}" multiselect="False" size="1" onclick="rerender">
            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="otherPanel,values" action="{!specifyVendor}"/>
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!vendors}"/>
        </apex:selectList><p/>
    </apex:outputPanel>
    <br/>
    <apex:outputPanel id="otherPanel">
        <apex:inputText value="{!otherVendor}" rendered="{!vendor=='Other'}"> Other: </apex:inputText>
    </apex:outputPanel>
    <br></br>
    You have selected:&nbsp;
    <apex:outputText value="{!displaySelectedText}" label="You have selected:" id="values" />  
</apex:form>
```

**Controller**

```
public with sharing class ExcelPageController {
 public String vendor {get; set;}//Vendor Name
 public String otherVendor {get; set;}//Vendor Name
 public string displaySelectedText {get;set;}

     public List<SelectOption> getVendors(){
         System.debug('getVendors');    
         List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
         options.add(new SelectOption('Cisco','Cisco'));
         options.add(new SelectOption('Alcatel','Alcatel'));
         options.add(new SelectOption('Tibco','Tibco'));
         options.add(new SelectOption('Other','Other'));
         return options;
     }

     public PageReference specifyVendor(){
        displaySelectedText  = vendor;
        System.debug(vendor);
        return null;
    }
 }
```

It will show like this:

[image: Input field formatting]

Comment: Thank you, I tried your code but the inputText is still not rendered

Comment: then something you have done wrong. just take this entire code and run at your DE

Comment: I copy/pasted your code and I added an action to the apex:actionSupport that contains System.debug(vendor). Looking in the System.debug, vendor seems to not change at all. Further I edit my code so you can see the changes.

Comment: Updated the code with little addition of outputText which is getting populated from specifyVendor(). Please close this question

Comment: I update the cose like you said Santanu, but loking in the System debug seems that specyfyVendor is not fired, i.e. vendor doesn't appear in the System debug anywhere

Comment: vendor is showing in debug I have checked, that's why displayText is showing correctly upon rendering.

Comment: it means that there's something in the rest of the my page that doesn't work correctly. Thank you Santanu, I'll work on the rest of the page and I'll see what happend

Comment: Please accept and close this ans so other member can find this useful