# Text field dependency from picklist

Tags: visualforce, page-layout, dependent-picklist, text

I am aware that field dependencies can only be created on Picklist and checkbox fields.

What I am trying to achieve is the following: when a certain value from a picklist field is selected, some TEXT fields will be shown on the page.

For example: I have a picklist with the following values:
A
B
If A is selected, text fields One and Two will be visible on the page.
If B is selected, text fields, Three and Four will be visible on the page.

I did some research and I read this could be achievable with Visualforce, but I'm pretty new with it and I'm not sure how this should be done.

Could anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: Is picklist on standard object or Custom?

Answer (score 0):

@robruf, have a look on the answer of this question, it is similar to your requirement- [Render an InputText based on Selected Option](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/149330/render-an-inputtext-based-on-selected-option)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Satrang Auto Number Helper app, this app enables users to assign the AutoNumber values to records based on Picklist Values or Record Types.

AppExchange Link - https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N30000000puTcEAI&tab=d

Disclaimer: I work at Satrang Technologies, the publisher of this Satrang Update Client Details ExchangeApp.